# Can't get a sticky footer working - trying everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've got the site JobCreatr.com. It is based on Drupal.

I am trying everything I can to get a sticky footer working and it just isn't working.

Currently I'm using the following jQuery to do it:

```
(function ($) {

$(function(){
    positionFooter(); 
    function positionFooter(){
        var padding_top = $("#footer-wrapper").css("padding-top").replace("px", "");
        var page_height = $(document.body).height() - padding_top;
        var window_height = $(window).height();
        var difference = window_height - page_height;
        if (difference < 0) 
            difference = 0;

        $("#footer-wrapper").css({
            padding: difference + "px 0 0 0"
        })
    }

    $(window)
        .resize(positionFooter)
});

})(jQuery);
```

Which as far as I can tell, should dynamically adjust footer size.

I've also tried absolute positioning, etc with CSS.

I'm at a loss at why it isn't working. I just want to have a uniform height footer on all pages, with no white space underneath.

Comment: Why would you use JS for this?

Comment: Because CSS wasn't working, so I was going with a "hack-ish" solution. I'd prefer css.

Comment: http://cleanstickyfooter.herokuapp.com/ looks pretty simple to implement.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? It looks pretty working now (there is no whitespace underneath)

Comment: Except that there's a big black box right above the footer, if there's enough space. The footer itself is fine, but that black section is not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Add this on you `#footer-wrapper` position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; border: 0px;`
2. I see `width: 80%;` on `.container` remove that.

See this preview and edited it thorugh Chrome Dev Tools:
[image]

Comment: I have tried that, and it did not seem to work. I will try again.

Comment: Hrm, but if you notice, the actual footer still extends pretty high. Like for example, I want it to only be a certain size in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try, something more like:

```
(function($){
  function positionFooter(){
    var padding_top = $('#footer-wrapper').css('padding-top').replace('px', '');
    var page_height = $(document.body).height() - padding_top;
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var difference = window_height - page_height;
    if(difference < 0)difference = 0;
    $('#footer-wrapper').css({padding: difference+'px 0 0 0'});
  }
  positionFooter();
  $(window).resize(positionFooter);
})(jQuery);
```

Remember that a line break in JavaScript is similar to `;`. Where I put the `positionFooter()` function doesn't make a difference.